# Twitter created_at time to unix timestamp in ruby

Tags: ruby, unix, twitter, timestamp

Is there a nice way to convert the timestamp you get from twitter (shown below) into a nice unix timestamp using ruby?

```
Tue, 05 Apr 2011 12:33:00 +0000
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Time.parse` to convert it to Ruby `Time` and `Time#to_i` to get your Unix time.

```
# Load the Time.parse method.
require 'time'

Time.parse('Tue, 05 Apr 2011 12:33:00 +0000').to_i
#=> 1302006780
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Works just how I had hoped.